# Dear Spider-Man

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, story

> deAr spider-man,
>
> you stopped me once before but nOt this time again. what you do not
> understand is That evolution is inevItable. i am merely speeding up
> this process. yes, people will become weird dry-skinned reptiles afteR
> this, but this is a sacrifice humanity has to make to improve. i have
> hiddEn my device at the top of the most wonderful of places, which
> will release its chemicals on christmas day, my gift to you all. i am
> afraid this time, you will Not have enough time to stop me.
>
> in this letter, i also included a block of letters. this is not my
> iDea. my friends insisted that i send you this since it is "more fun".
> well, technically not my friends. just some people from someplace
> called "gofam" who are interested in my work. one of them oNly wears a
> green suit while the other dResses like a dumb clown, but hey, who am
> i to judge their appearance.
>
> i am soRry that you do not understand the brilliance of my plan. maybe
> you would learn to appreciate what i do a bit more after you gain
> reGenerative powers.
>
> yours faitHfully,
> curt connors
> (edited by thE r and j)

---

```
NERQUREEVAT
ADCLHHWIRNA
ADNRFGKOOQN
JGADOBFRAAB
XTTNTAWAIZO
EFSEAATRYHT
ERILYCEIUDS
FKKOSGRAADW
LQALIAYBILA
TVPNGUYANAN
IKOMSPVAAXA
```

---

You looked at your friend. Well, technically not your friend. Just some random dude with a black cape who flew into your apartment, scared the living daylights out of Aunt May, and handed you the letter.

"Well." He spoke with an unnecessarily low voice. "Where is the device hidden?"

---

Your answer is a location that exists in real life.

Hint:

> "I found all the capitals in this letter and I think they can be rearranged to form a message!"

Comment: If you ignore the red herring, I can find 3 of that mentioned group, 4 of another famous group, and one odd one out. But it doesn't feel like it's the final answer.

Comment: Have no idea what to do with this: rot13(Gur pncvgnyvmrq yrggref fcryy bhg na nantenz sbe 'ABG N ERQ UREEVAT')

Comment: @LukasRotter Can you elaborate on the 'groups'?

Comment: @newQOpenWid The remaining letters of the REDHERRING anagram are AOTN, so I thought maybe this hints towards NATO (3/8), 4 of the remaining are commonwealth countries (although Canada is both CW and in NATO), leaving Libya. I didn't even realize the anagram just means "NOT A red herring" - so its almost certainly a dead-end

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer builds from Lezzup's answer.  To recap, the grid of letters contains

> the name of eight countries:
>
>  Botswana
>  Guyana
>  Nigeria
>  Norway
>  Pakistan
>  Croatia
>  Libya
>  Canada

Now:

> The hint says "I found all the capitals in this letter and I think they can be rearranged to form a message!".  Instead of the capital *letters* which spell out "not a red herring", this hint refers to the capital *cities* of the eight countries, which are:
>
>  Gaborone, Botswana
>  Georgetown, Guyana
>  Abuja, Nigeria
>  Oslo, Norway
>  Islamabad, Pakistan
>  Zagreb, Croatia
>  Tripoli, Libya
>  Ottawa, Canada

Then:

> Taking the first letter of each capital city, we have **GGAOIZTO**.  This anagrams to **GO TO GIZA**.  We know from the letter that the device is hidden "at the top of the most wonderful of places".  If we are in Giza, this means that the device must be hidden **on top of the Great Pyramid**, which was one of the seven *wonders* of the ancient world.

Comment: perhaps you could elaborate on rot13(Frira jbaqref)?

Answer (score 9):

First, let's find out who the friends are of Curt Connors:

> "gofam" means probably Gotham, and that means we have to look for some DC vilains. The one with the green suit is **The Riddler**, and the one that dresses like a dumb clown, is the **Joker**. This explains the last sentence:
>  (edited by thE r and j) => (edited by The Riddler and Joker)

After that, it's quite obvious who is the friend of Spider-Man:

> The one with the black cape and unnecessary low voice is **Batman**!

About all the capital letters:

> They spell out `AOTIRENDNRRGHE`, which is an anagram for `Not a red herring`. No idea what to do with that.

Let's find out what's with the grid with letters means:

> The first row spells out `NERQUREEVAT` which is rot13: `A RED HERRING`. So let's ignore that one.
>  It's actually a word-search! In the grid, 8 countries could be found:
>  [image: wordsearch]
>  Botswana
>  Guyana
>  Nigeria
>  Norway
>  Pakistan
>  Croatia
>  Libya
>  Canada

"i have hiddEn my device at the top of the most wonderful of places", so the final answer is probably:

> The highest mountains in these countries:
>
> ```
> Botswana   Monalanong Hill
>
> Guyana     Mount Roraima
>
> Nigeria    Chabbal Waddi
>
> Norway     Galdhøpiggen
>
> Pakistan   K2
>
> Croatia    DINARA
>
> Libya      Bikku Bitti
>
> Canada     Mount Logan
> ```

Comment: I don't think that's the right answer, though, as it's too general. I think it must have something to do with the exact countries themselves.

Comment: @Lezzup, this is a very good attempt. Note that new Q Open Wid is right that this is not the final intended solution.

Comment: @CatProgrammer, now we are all weird dry-skinned reptiles :)

Comment: @WOWOW well it isn't Christmas day yet ;)

Comment: @lezzup Hint for everyone, rot13 (Nsgre lbh erneenatr gur pncvgny yrggref, lbh ner gbyq guvf vf abg n erq ureevat. Ubj vf guvf eryrinag gb rvtug pbhagevrf? )

Comment: A word search would also allow for plenty of nonsense words: TRAVELER HARDLY FROGS BROW ZONE THEY SKILL DRAW BALL YAN VAX...

Comment: Maybe the countries or mountains are red herrings.

Comment: @The_AH rot13(Gur pbhagevrf ner va gur evtug qverpgvba, whfg abg zbhagnvaf...V jbaqre jung ryfr pbhyq or eryngrq gb n pbhagel...?)

Comment: @CatProgrammer rot13(V pnzr hc jvgu "ngb(c) Mvttb" ohg vg frrzf yvxr n fgergpu naq gur "c" vf zvffvat.  Nz V naljurer pybfr?)

Comment: @JS1, your technique is right, but your answer is wrong. Perhaps a hint would come from rot 13(ng gur gbc bs gur zbfg jbaqreshy bs cynprf)

Comment: @CatProgrammer rot13(V'z ng "tb gb Tvmn" juvpu V guvax zrnaf gur gbc bs gur Terng Clenzvq?  Vs gung'f evtug, V'yy jevgr hc na nafjre.)

Comment: @JS1, I think it is time for you to get in the batplane rn.

Comment: @JS1, Nu, V unq gur fnzr yrggref sbhaq zlfrys, ohg pbhyqa'g trg n zrnavatshy nafjre. V gubhtug znlor 'Tvtn Mbb', ohg qvqa'g srry evtug. ohg V arire gubhtug nobhg 'Tb gb Tvmn'. Should I edit the answer, or would you create the answer yourself?

Comment: @Lezzup rot13(V fcrag n ybg bs gvzr cynlvat nebhaq jvgu gubfr yrggref.  Nf lbh pna frr sebz zl rneyvre pbzzrag, gur orfg V pnzr hc jvgu jnf "ngb(c) Mvttb", jurer Mvttb vf n ohvyqvat va gur Argureynaqf.  Vg jnf bayl nsgre PngCebtenzzre'f fhofrdhrag pbzzrag gung V fgnegrq ybbxvat sbe snzbhf uvtu cynprf engure guna fbyivat gur nantenz.  V'z cerggl fher vg jnf ol yhpx gung V znantrq gb abgvpr "tvmn" ol frnepuvat sbe "yvfg bs gnyy ohvyqvatf" naq fbzr jrofvgr zragvbarq gur terng clenzvq nf uvfgbevpnyyl gur gnyyrfg ohvyqvat hagvy zbqrea gvzrf.)

Comment: @JS1, haha, so a nice challenge indeed :) congrats on finding it, I've upvoted your answer